# emacs icicles error on start

Tags: emacs, icicles

Icicles (v.22.0) installed from elpa (package-list-packages)

Emacs version

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.0.90.1
```

Output on emacs start

Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/exu/.emacs.d/init.el':

```
Symbol's function definition is void: hexrgb-canonicalize-defined-colors
```

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

Debug init below: 
[Link to GIST error dump](https://gist.github.com/1297660)

Comment: This would be better suited as a bug report to the mailing list. I'd usually say "Welcome to SO, make sure to read the FAQ and have a nice time" but you seem to be here long enough to know better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not get such an error.  Sorry for your trouble.  The error message is saying that something tried to call function `hexrgb-canonicalize-defined-colors` but it was never defined.  It was not defined no doubt because you do not have file `hexrgb.el` in your `load-path`.  That's OK, but in that case, it should never be called.

[`hexrgb.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hexrgb.el) is an *optional* file for using **Icicles** (but it is recommended) -- see [optional **Icicles** libraries](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Libraries#Optional).

Follow up by email, if you can -- that's easiest: `M-x icicle-send-bug-report`.  Let me know what **Icicles** files you have etc.  Preferably, test by starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).   Set `debug-on-error` to t, add the **Icicles** files to your `load-path`, `M-x-load-library icicles`, etc.

For debugging, use only the *source* **Icicles** files (`*.el`, not byte-compiled, `*.elc`).  Remove any byte-compiled **Icicles** files from your `load-path`.  Thx -- Drew

Comment: Great - i've start icicles installing "by hand" without elpa and now it works, your debug steps save my day :)

Comment: Would you mind sending me an email to detail the ELPA problems you ran into? You should be able to install Icicles from ELPA too. Perhaps I need to tweak an autoload cookie or something. It would help me and possibly others if you could let me know a little more about the problems encountered. Thx -- Drew

Comment: I took a closer look, and I think you just got hold of an outdated version of Icicles. There was a short period in the past when there was a problem with som hexrgb.el autoload cookies.  Also, I'm surprised to hear that you used ELPA.  I am not aware of Icicles being available anywhere via ELPA. Can you please let me know where you obtained Icicles via ELPA?  Again, email is best.  Thx -- Drew

Comment: Icicles is on list (v 22.0 / maybe from marmelade repo?) I have 2 repos on ELPA: http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/, and http://tromey.com/elpa/, after standard install (package-list-packages) and _install_ link, ELPA installs all dependencies (hexrgb-21.0  icomplete+-21.0  lacarte-22.0  synonyms-1.0) Icicles works without this dependencies.